# I cannot compile a C file with a dynamic 2D array and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

**Edit:** Yeah I know that I already have a 3x100 array without the need of doing all of this. But the issue is that I don't know what size the array will be, it will change depending on the case. That's why I wanted to make it dynamic.

I get this warning when compiling:

> c1.c:24:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type >[-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>     copieTab = tabClef;

Apparently *copieTab* is not compatible with *tabClef* and thus can't have its value assigned.

I create a dynamic 2D array that has 3 rows and 100 columns. Here is my code:

```
void allocation(size_t longClef, int copieTab[3][100]) {
  int i=0;
  int ** tabClef = NULL;
  tabClef = malloc(longClef * sizeof(char));

  if (tabClef == NULL) //Si l'allocation a echoue
  {
    printf("Allocation a echoue\n");
    return; // On arrete immediatement le programme
  }
  // On peut continuer le programme normalement sinon

  // Creer matrice
  for (i=0; i<longClef; i++) {
    tabClef[i] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
  }

  /* Copie du tableau dans un pointeur pour le sortir de la fonction */
  copieTab = tabClef;
}
```

Comment: you cannot assign an allocated list of pointers to a 2D array. why not writing directly in `copieTab` ?

Comment: note that your pointer/array element type is `int` and you're allocating wrong sizes for both. Should be `sizeof(int *)` and `sizeof(int)` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

> the issue is that I don't know what size the array will be

OP's code is a nice attempt , but quite unsuitable to allocating a 2D dynamically sized array.

Allocate an array of `row` `int *` pointers.
`row` times, allocate an array of `col` `int`.
Return the pointer from the 1st step.

```
int **alloc_2D_dynamic_int(size_t row, size_t col) {
  int **table = malloc(sizeof *table * row);
  if (table == NULL) Oops();  // TBD error handling
  for (size_t r = 0; r < row; r++) {
    table[r] = malloc(sizeof *(table[r]) * col);
    if (table[r] == NULL) Oops();
  }
  return table;
}
```

On freeing, reverse the steps.

```
void free_2D_dynamic_int(int **table, size_t row) {
  if (table) {
    for (size_t r = 0; r < row; r++) {
      free(table[r]);
    }
    free(table);     
  }
}
```

---

Otherwise perhaps OP's wants to allocate memory for a 2D array

```
void alloc_2D_int(size_t row, size_t col, int (**table)[row][col]) {
  *table = malloc(sizeof(**table));
}
```

Or return the allocated pointer

```
void *alloc_2D_int_R(size_t row, size_t col) {
  int (*table)[row][col] = malloc(sizeof *table);
  return table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that. A 2d array decays into pointer to first element - here it (`copieTab`) will be of type  `int(*)[100]` and you are assigning to it, the value of `int**`. That's why the compiler message.

There are couple of options to get rid of this:-

1. Return the dynamically allocated memories address from the function and assign it to a `int**`.

   ```
    int** a;
    a = allocation(2);
    ...
   ```

Other function:

```
      int ** allocation (size_t sz){
         ..
         return tabClef;
      }
```

Use it like

```
     printf("%d",a[i][j]);
```

2. Or if it already an 2d array of `int` then you just pass it alone the functions to get input on it. No need to dynamically allocate.

   ```
   int row;
   //get input in row.
   int a[row][100]; // Variable length array.
   ...
   func(row,a);
   ```

Func:

```
    void func(int row, int a[][100]){
    ...// work with 'a' here. You can make changes to it.
    }
```

3. Or pass `int**` to allocation function and then make changes to it. (Asks you for use of 3 level pointer - not recommended).

Apart from wrong amount of memory allocation - you didn't check for the return value of `malloc` while allocating second time.

Also note that you said you are dynamically creating arrays of size `3x100` but then you are allocating `longClef` number of `int*`.